# Ordering ACF Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having some trouble with ordering my output using Advanced Custom Fields in WordPress. they where working nicely before but I had to make some alterations.

So I need my list to order by the number of signups (meta field) and it was before, but now I have added another field it no longer orders them in a particular order.

```
    $posts = get_posts(array(
      'post_type'     => 'schools',
      'posts_per_page'  => -1,
      'meta_key'      => 'signups', 
      'orderby'     => 'meta_value_num',                 
      'meta_key'      => 'region',    
      'meta_value'  => 'SW1', 
      'order'       => 'DESC'                         
    ));
```

I have tried to lookup why but I am coming up stuck with it. So it is a leaderboard where by the highest number is at the top naturally and ascends down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out now:

```
    $posts = get_posts(array(
      'post_type'     => 'schools',
      'posts_per_page'  => -1,
      'meta_key'      => 'signups', 
      'orderby'     => 'meta_value_num',                  
      'order'       => 'DESC' ,  

      'meta_query'    => array(
      'relation'      => 'AND',
      array(
          'key'       => 'signups',
      ),
      array(
          'key'       => 'region',
          'value'     => 'EA1',
      ),          
      )

    ));
```